# Unsubscribing from subscriptions in socket.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

Let's say I have angular page with a table with 10 rows, that each row has an id, and redirects me to a page with unique id.

I want to subscribe to this id in socket.io, and when I will leave this page / change to another, I want to replace the previous subscription to the new one.

How can I do that? Do I have to save all my current subscriptions in a database?

(I work with sails.js framework on node, and angular on client).

Answer (score 0):

When you disconnect a socket (i.e. change page to another), socket.io unsuscribe your socket automatically.

To subscribe to a room, you could simply send a message from angular when you connect with the id and then in your sails controller you subscribe the user to the id

**EDIT**

Like [this](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/sails-sockets-socket-rooms) page says, you need to implement your system to track sockets.

First, create a service in /api/services/ and put that :

```
module.exports = {

    switchRoom: function (socket, to_id) {
        var tmp = _.find(sails.mysubscribers, function (sub) {
            return sub.socket === socket;
        });
        if (tmp) { // If user came from another page unsuscribe him
            sails.sockets.leave(socket, 'Unique prefix' + tmp.roomId);
        } else {
            tmp = {
                socket: socket
            };
            sails.mysubscribers.push(tmp);
        }

        if (!to_id) { // If the user leave remove him from the array
            var index = sails.mysubscribers.indexOf(tmp);
            if (index > -1) sails.mysubscribers.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            tmp.roomId = to_id;
            sails.sockets.join(socket, 'Unique prefix' + to_id);
        }
    }
};
```

Then, in /config/sockets.js edit the afterDisconnect function :

```
module.exports.sockets = {

    afterDisconnect: function (session, socket, cb) {
        YourService.switchRoom(socket);
        return cb();
    }
};
```

Now, when you need to switchRoom, you just have to call `YourService.switchRoom(req.socket, roomId)` where roomId is the id send by angular...

That's it !

Comment: But I use angular, so there is no real disconnection by page changes.